# Display Country On the basis of City ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have these tables:

```
Country(CountID,Cname)
State(Stateid,Sname,CountID)
City(CtyID, ctyname, Stateid)
User(name,Age,CityID)
```

where `City id` is the foreign key in `User` Table. `Country Id` is not foreign key in `User` Table.

I have to display: `Name, Age, Country`.

How can I display `Country` and all data of `User` Table in Result view in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.Name, u.Age, cy.Cname
FROM [User] u
INNER JOIN [City] c ON u.CityID = c.CityID
INNER JOIN [State] s ON c.Stateid = s.Stateid
INNER JOIN [Country] cy ON s.CountID = cy.CountID
```

Another comment mentioned the use of the keywords and quoting them to keep SQL from getting confused. If at all possible I'd suggest making your table names something distinct to the project, even something as simple as prefixing all tables with a character helps. Example would be instead of Users call the table QUsers and instead of State call the table QState. The arbitrary character ensures that you'll never have to worry about the table name becoming a SQL keyword in the future.

Comment: Thanks @Justin Savala